# How to use Phaser correctly?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, phaser

I have implemented `MyListener` which is accessed from two different threads.

```
class MyListener implements Listener {
    private final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(2);        

    @Override
    public void changed () {
        phaser.arrive();
    }

    public void await () {
        phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();    
    } 
}
```

I use it like this in main thread

```
MyListener listener = new Listener();
someObject.setListener(listener);     

doSomething(); //it would result in Listener.changed() being invoked
listener.await();

doSomething(); //it would result in Listener.changed() being invoked
listener.await();
```

I have several concerns:

1. Java docs states that calling `arrive()` and `arriveAndAwaitAdvance()` without calling `register()` first is not correct.
2. `changed()` might be invoked several times for the same event. I expect that one of `await()` might return immideately because of previous event.

**Any idea about this concerns?**

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: after every `doSomething()`, `listener.await()` should return only if `changed` was called by other thread.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first concern: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html#arrive()

says:

> It is a usage error for an unregistered party to invoke this method.

It does not state that the registration has to take place by calling `register()`. Specifying the number of pre-registered parties in the constructor as you do is a valid usage.

---

About the second, you *must not* call `arrive` multiple times. It is not clear what your intention of calling `changed()` several times for one event shall imply, is the other thread allowed to proceed on the first invocation, the last one (how to know that it is the last one?) or something in between?

It seems that you want to split the arrival, i.e. giving the other process the right to proceed, from the waiting for this permission. This is quite easy: don’t use the compound `arriveAndAwaitAdvance()`:

```
int currentPhase = phaser.arrive(); // allow the other thread to proceed
…
phaser.awaitAdvance(currentPhase); // wait for the other thread’s arrival
```

Comment: What this line actually mean or try to mean? "It is a usage error for an unregistered party to invoke this method."

Comment: exactly what it says on the tin

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. What does it mean by "unregistered party"?

Comment: I hope, you noticed that this is a cite from [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html). Did you read (and understand) it?

Comment: Surely, I did. Why would I not!? I just didn't understand the meaning/context of "unregistered party" used in the doc(or the line you cited). Did you understand it? If yes, then please let me know your words.

Comment: What word do you have difficulties with? “party”? That term is used a hundred times in the documentation. “unregistered”? It’s to opposite of “registered” and the fact that there is a number of registered parties is fundamental to that class, that’s why you can [register a number of parties in the constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html#Phaser(int)) or [register](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html#register()) them on by one, etc. I have no idea what you can’t understand in that context.